# Python to get specific last 2 or 3 characters

Tags: python

I'm looking for a Python script that will get the last 2 or 3 specific characters. To be more specific, I'm looking to cut the IP name to the last 2 or 3 digits.

```
import socket
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())[-3:0]
```

I was thinking of just slicing the ip address and get the last 3 digits but figured that will give me issues when the IP address ends with 2 digits (i.e. 192.168.1.XX)

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: `ip.split('.')[-1]`

Answer (score 6):

```
import socket
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()).split('.')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to `lstrip` a possibly leading `'.'`:

```
import socket
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())[-3:].lstrip('.')
```

An example:

```
ip1 = '192.168.1.10'
ip2 = '192.168.1.100'
print(ip1[-3:].lstrip('.'))
>> 10
print(ip2[-3:].lstrip('.'))
>> 100
```